# Creating a Mac OS X title bar-style menu with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web site. The type of menu that I want to create is one where you click on something in the menu, and a submenu pops up. But then you can also hover over any other menu item and another submenu will come up, hiding the first one you clicked. You can click anywhere to close the submenu.

I hope that was clear enough, and would appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: have you looked at something like Ext JS  http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/ or Dojo Toolkit http://dojotoolkit.org/ ?

Comment: Isn't that how Windows menus work too?

Comment: I don't know too much about using EXT JS or Dojo. I wouldn't use them unless they have these features that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's my very, very simple, cheap, brief, ugly, lazy, father-disappointing version](http://jsfiddle.net/uw4U9/4/). It uses jQuery, and it probably doesn't actually look anything like what you wanted. But it accomplishes (I think) the one important thing: "locking" the sub-menu open until either another one is opened, or the user clicks somewhere else on the page.

The HTML looks like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="author" href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        <ul class="books">
            <li><a class="book" href="#">Sub-Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="book" href="#">Sub-Menu Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

...and here's the JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    var $current,
        closeSubMenu = function () {
            if ($current) {
                $current.slideUp();
            }
        },
        openSubMenu = function (e) {
            var $books = $(this).next();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (!$current || $current[0] !== $books[0]) {
                closeSubMenu();
                $current = $books;
                $books.slideDown();
            }
        };

    $(document).click(function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.hasClass('author')) {
                openSubMenu.call(e.target, e);
            } else if ($target.hasClass('book')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                closeSubMenu();
                $current = null;
            }
        });
    $('.books').slideUp();
}(jQuery));
```

If nothing else, it should help give you some ideas for how you *do* decide to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added this code in and it is much closer to what I want. The only thing is i dont want the submenu to automatically open on hover. I want you to have to click on it to open

Comment: @Ian Not a problem. All you have to do is get rid of the `.delegate( ... )` stuff. I've updated my code to demonstrate.

Comment: Ok thanks. Any way to make it so I click to open the first one, then the rest can be navigated to by hovering over their titles? kind of a combination of both, and the way the menu bar works in Mac OS X

Comment: @Ian I don't actually use Macs, so I'm kind of guessing my way through all of this... [But is this what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/uw4U9/5/) You have to click to open the sub-menu at the beginning, but once it's open, you can hover over the other menus.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Menu bars all work the same on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Well the only reason I pointed out it was like the Mac was because I am using Dreamweaver right now on Win7 and the menus don't work like that :)